# The image Url gets null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

```
 Future uploadImageToFirebase() async{
    FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    StorageReference reference = _storage.ref().child("Products/${Path.basename(_image.path)}");
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(_image);
    await uploadTask.onComplete;
    reference.getDownloadURL().then((fileURL) {
      setState(() {
        url = fileURL.toString();
      });
    });
    print(url);
  }
```

the URL returns null if the function is called for the first time but if I call it again it returns the correct URL. Please help me figure out what is wrong with the code.
If I click on the RaiseButton once it returns null, but if I click the second time it returns the correct URL.

```
W/StorageUtil( 9524): no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest( 9524): no auth token for request
I/System.out( 9524): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out( 9524): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/StorageUtil( 9524): no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest( 9524): no auth token for request
I/System.out( 9524): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out( 9524): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/StorageUtil( 9524): no auth token for request
I/flutter ( 9524): null
W/NetworkRequest( 9524): no auth token for request
I/System.out( 9524): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out( 9524): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/ViewRootImpl@8f09ed9[MainActivity]( 9524): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@8f09ed9[MainActivity]( 9524): ViewPostIme pointer 1
W/StorageUtil( 9524): no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest( 9524): no auth token for request
I/System.out( 9524): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out( 9524): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/StorageUtil( 9524): no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest( 9524): no auth token for request
I/System.out( 9524): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out( 9524): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/flutter ( 9524): https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bridcodes-seller.appspot.com/o/Products%2Fimage_cropper_1598948384298.jpg?alt=media&token=cc418efc-8402-4a96-a0f0-939a3a171373
W/StorageUtil( 9524): no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest( 9524): no auth token for request
I/System.out( 9524): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out( 9524): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

This is my firebase storage security rules.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /Products/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: update your security rule in firebase storage

Comment: Have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/63297466/13840864 This should help you understand how `then` works.

Comment: I looked at this solution still it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Future<String> uploadImageToFirebase() async {
    FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    StorageReference reference = _storage.ref().child("Products/${Path.basename(_image.path)}");
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(_image);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    final String url = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return url;
  }
```

Calling function

```
    uploadDetails(context) async {
    if(_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      if(_image != null) {
        imgUrl = await uploadImageToFirebase();
        Firestore.instance.collection("Products").add({
          'ImgUrl': imgUrl,
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does the issue persist with this code? I see that you are assigning the awaited value from the onComplete method, that looks like a better way to catch the relevant resulting object.